# Is there an explicit formula for this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say I have the series
$$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$
where
$$a_n=a_1(1-s_{n-1})$$
$$a_1\in(0,1)$$

As you can see, to calculate $s_n$ I need to calculate $s_{n-1}$ first. Is there any way I can simplify $s_n$ such that I just need to plug in the $n$?

Comment: *Hint:* Write this as a recursion formula for $s_n$.

Comment: If you experiment with a few different values of $a_1$ and look at $1-s_n$ for small $n$ then you might be able to spot a pattern, especially if you compare them to $1-a_1$

Comment: I think $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$.

Comment: @gpassante Yeah, my bad.

Comment: Hint: $a_n =s_n-s_{n-1}$. What you have here is called a linear recursion.